# jQuery tablesorter 2.0, resorting table after values change

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I need to re-sort a table when the input elements in cells change in value. I've already created custom sorters for my data, which works wonderfully, but now I need to re-sort when data changes.

`$('#id').tablesorter(...)` almost does what I need, but it seems to apply ANOTHER set of sorting on a given table, which leads to really weird behavior. Is there a way to completely redo the tablesorting action, or at least for the table to resort based on new information?

From building the custom parser, I see that tablesorter builds the formatted columns and stores it internally once when the page loads, and I need to modify this behavior such that I can resort on `$('#id input').change`.

Any ideas? The documentation for this plugin is weak, although it is a great plugin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i think what you need to do is trigger an update.

```
$("#tableId").trigger("update");
```

that's what i'm doing to make my tables resort.

i agree with you the documentation for this plugin is weak as best.

Comment: At least the source code is clean enough :P. I'll try these methods out in a bit.

Comment: yup, it's pretty nice looking code, i think that is how i found this.

Comment: I have a major problem with this solution. My table is at least 150 rows * 18 columns (Stock Market Trading Website). 'update' just hangs my UI totally, because a lot of values change in 1 sec, so i might be calling update 4 or 5 times / second. Any other solution??

Comment: @roshdy I would can the update every X seconds instead of every time a cell gets update.

Comment: @Patricia that's what i ended up doing,  and it's very fast. 1 sec update rate.

Answer (score 4):

Are you referring to:

```
$("#id").trigger("update");
```